# ThreadPool or Timers tasks are not waiting properly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

After updating Android's Support Libraries (v28.0+) to get targeted with monoandroid90, the app crashes sometimes with the stack trace I provided bellow. If there are breakpoints active this won't happen.

Different versions of Xamarin.Android were tested, the current one I'm using is the latest 9.4 that comes with the default vs19. I was **not able** to reproduce this on a fresh install of the vs17 with the default XA that comes with it (9.1.7.0)

The following stack trace shows the current problem I'm facing.

```
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00007>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0002b] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0

"Finalizer"08-06 16:26:25.748 E/mono    (11487): Full thread dump:


"Thread Pool Worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00007>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0002b] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0

"Debugger agent"

"Timer-Scheduler"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.Wait_internal (intptr*,int,bool,int) <0x00007>
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,uint,bool,bool) [0x0001f] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle,long,bool,bool) [0x00019] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (long,bool) [0x00010] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (int,bool) [0x0001d] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (int) [0x00003] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.Timer/Scheduler.SchedulerThread () [0x00043] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x0001f] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00073] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00004] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002f] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00014] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00067] in <ff07eae8184a40a08e79049bbcb31a0e>:0

"<unnamed thread>"
08-06 16:26:35.755 I/libc    (11487): Requested dump for tid 11487 (ler.challengeme)
```

Anybody else has ever faced this issue and is aware of a possible solution?

Comment: I feel like this is better suited in GitHub issues in the xamarin-android repo.

Comment: Done, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3456

Comment: A stacktrace indicates where an exception was thrown. It doesn't paint a complete picture without the exception itself, which is left out. This is telling us there's *some* exception. What is it?

Comment: There's no other exception elsewhere, checked the logcat too. Increased output level on visual studio, nothing new came up